# how can I make Flutter app permanently connected to a BLE device (even after systems reboots)

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to find a way to connect a Flutter app to a BLE beacon physical button whose purpose is to, when pressed, send an email through the app. So, I want the app to be permanently connected to the button and listen to its inputs, whether it's in foreground, background or terminated state. Even after a system reboot, I want it to always connect automatically and listen. What would be the best approach to do so, as I've seen that Android and iOS behave differently towards BLE devices as well as background processes.

I tried using packages like 'flutter_blue' or 'workmanager'. However, isolates created by workmanager can only run every at least 15 minutes on iOS. I am new to working with BLE devices as well as background processes in Flutter.

Comment: The exact thing you're asking for is done and explained here: https://github.com/50ButtonsEach/flic2lib-android#background-execution, with the exception that you also want to add a Flutter UI to the app. For iOS, see "state preservation and restoration" in order to learn how iOS can restart a killed app when a 
pending bluetooth connection gets fulfilled or a GATT notification arrives.

Comment: I am now using the package 'flutter_background_service' and the app remains connected to the device (on Android) even after it is terminated and responses accordingly every time I press the button. However, after system reboot, the process doesn't start.

Comment: Haven't done the iOS part yet, but does the button have to notify the device for connection? Because my BLE devices is not paired or doesn't try to connect with the phone, only vice-versa. I'm not really sure how BLE works, so I might be mistaking. You think "state preservation and restoration" can work in my case on iOS? Thanks